# Why does Google Analytics set a 1st party cookie even when its script is sourced from Google's domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am curious about the mechanism behind how Google Analytics cookies are classified as 1st party cookies. The script tag's src attribute points to Google's domain, which is different from the domain of the page it's embedded in. One hypothesis I have is that the Google Analytics JavaScript, when executed on the embedded page, generates cookies using document.cookie. Is the domain where document.cookie is executed the determining factor for whether a cookie is classified as a 1st party or 3rd party cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the domain where document.cookie is executed the determining factor for whether a cookie is classified as a 1st party or 3rd party cookie?

The relevant origin for JavaScript code is the *page's* origin, not the origin the script was loaded from. So yes, if a page on `https://example.com` uses JavaScript code loaded from `https://google.com`, and that code sets a cookie via `document.cookie`, it's an `https://example.com` cookie.

Third-party cookies are created via the `Set-Cookie` header in a response to a request for a third-party resource. For instance, in the scenario above, if the HTTP response for the script had a `Set-Cookie` header, it would be trying to set a third-party cookie for `https://google.com`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had this question for a long time and now it's much clearer!